# Fixed Feedback button on the side of LEFT or RIGHT side of the window?

Tags: buttons, feedback, tabs, placement

**My start up [WEBSITE] is going to be launching in private beta soon and we're trying to decide where our feedback button/tab should go.**

We've looked at how [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com) does theirs (bottom right) and how [Get Satisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com) (left side - middle of the page) does theirs but now we're even more confused...

**So we would like to know (keep in mind it's private beta so the more noticeable the better as we want feedback from our users)...**

1. Which side is more likely to be noticed more? Left or right hand side?
2. If either Left or Right, should it be on the bottom? Or the fixed to the side?
3. Is there a significant difference between any of these options?

Comment: Is this an app or a website?

Comment: Sorry, It's a website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet would be to do some A/B testing. Something you might want to consider is the visual design of your website. For example, do you have a left reel that a button might distract against, or maybe the the right side is more graphic laden. Consider how basic design principles (e.g. contrast, proximity) might draw/divert attention.

I'd also recommend being smart about your analytics and prompting for feedback at the right moment. For example, magazines/blogs recommend related articles that slide out (this is the prompt using movement as design principle to draw attention) when you reach the bottom of the page (cue). Similarly, if the user is on a page for too long, you might trigger your dialog to offer help. Once they complete a transaction, you might remind them to offer feedback.

Answer (score 2):

By seeking feedback you're asking users to do something for you - *to do you a favour*.

Providing a service and saying 'once you're done, let us know what you think.' just does not work. Once people are done with the service, they rarely go back and find the feedback form. I've seen this happen where no-one gave feedback because the request for feedback came via the original email with a link to the website beta.

So how do you get people to give feedback? You have to appeal to the subconscious element of the user to make them *want* to give feedback. In order to do that you are targeting the *goodwill* of the user. This means that you want to make the user feel as though you have done them a favour first and that they have a duty to respond by doing you a favour back.

Often this *reciprocal* behaviour is magnified and users will respond by doing much more of a favour than you gave them in the first place.

So where I'm going with this is that when asking for feedback, it's not about location, it's about timing. By placing a feedback banner on the page from the beginning, you may actually be diminishing the likelihood of getting a response because it's being displayed before it's required, and the impulse reaction is lost, with users getting used to it being there and feeling that it's irrelevant when they first visit because they haven't any feedback to give yet.

At some point in your service, you will hopefully have provided the user with a service and at a critical point the user should have a sense of completion or achievement and be feeling positive about the service. Yes - I know you're looking to collect negative feedback from the journey - but nevertheless, the journey must end, and that's the most likely peak of positivity and accomplishment.

At this point - when you have built up this goodwill or *indebtedness*, *that's* the time to appeal to them and get the impulse reciprocity reaction that makes them provide feedback.

So think about how you can tie in your feedback to this sequence of events, and position your request or alert in such a way as to provoke a reaction in this natural pause - where the user is not being interrupted, and has a fairly full pot of goodwill. By the way - if there are glaring issues that mean that pot of goodwill might never be filled, you should rectify them before putting out a beta and asking for feedback. Don't release what you *know* to be annoying because feedback on that will eclipse all the other things you really wanted feedback on.

In addition you might want to consider *combining the reciprocity with reward* and inform the user that they can receive a discount on the service when it goes live, or receive an exclusive invite at time of release - or something suitable, and relevant, and attractive depending on your service and your target audience. But you must do this at the same time as requesting the feedback. In tests, reciprocity beats reward by two to one. Don't offer the reward beforehand, wait until the reciprocal moment - then compound it with the reward offer.

*Tip*: Don't go all out and use up all your potential beta userbase in one go. Plan ahead to do it in stages, iterate quickly on initial feedback that will allow you to hone in on the most commonly referred issues, fix/improve them and repeat, preferably with a different userbase.

For more details:

- [Neuro Web Design, What' makes them click?](https://web.archive.org/web/20130125004252/http://www.theteamw.com:80/books/) by Susan Weinschenk.
- [Embedded Persuasive Strategies to Obtain Visitors’ Data: Comparing Reward and Reciprocity in an Amateur, Knowledge-Based Website](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-77006-0_24) by Luciano Gamberini, Giovanni Petrucci, Andrea Spoto and Anna Spagnolli

**tl;dr** - Left, Right, Bottom - there is no single right answer - to elicit a response, you need to appeal to a much deeper subconscious emotion in the brain than just a left/right preference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a mobile app I would recommend fixed to the right side of the screen. I wouldn't use neither the navigation bar (header) or tab bar (menu) of the app. These because I think one of the things you are trying to test on your beta is UX-UI, so feedback button would interrupt the normal navigation of your app.

In the case you are building a webpage I would recommend bottom right. Not in the top because in general web headers display a lot of information, so the feedback button might not be noticed. Instead in the bottom you have free space. At the right and not left because the exercise that the eye makes when scanning any object, webpage or graphic is from upper left to bottom right, in diagonal. So this way it's more natural to notice your feedback button.